# Human Blood vessels,

Tags: human-biology

Why is blood drawn from veins? Is it because veins have a large lumen? Or is it because the blood is flowing at a lower pressure and makes discharge easier? Is it safer to draw blood from veins?

Answer (score 3):

If you draw blood from arteries,it will spout out because the arterial blood flows at some pressure. Moreover, it is too hard to stick a needle because arteries consist of thick blood walls.